# Device or Resource Busy Error when reading from chip on embedded device

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, i2c, usrp

I have an application that I have cross-compiled for the USRP N310 embedded device that reads from the TCA6408 I/O Expander on the daughterboard using the built-in Linux I2C driver. The printout I receive when running this application is a string error "Device or Resource Busy" when trying to set the slave address of the device. From research on the usrp N310 it appears that the Module Peripheral Manager(MPM) daemon "owns" the SPI and I2C interfaces on the device. So, I disabled the service using the `"systemctl disable <service>"` command rebooted the device. After reboot, I'm still getting the same error. In addition, `i2cdetect -r 9` shows `UU` for the particular device that I'm trying to read from which indicates that there is a driver already occupying the device. However, the `lsmod` command doesn't show any loaded modules that relate to I2C. As mentioned in one of the responses below, I tried to see which module may be holding the device by going under the /sys directory, however, my directory structure is different from the one listed in the response in that I don't have a module directory. Under/sys/bus/i2c/devices/9-0020/driver/9-0020, however, it does have a file 'modalias" which lists `of:Ngpio(null)Cti,tca6408` which at the moment I'm unsure if this is an alias to the actual driver for the chip. Another method I tried was using the `udev` command which doesn't show a driver for the actual device but lists "cdns-i2c" as a driver associated with a parent devices as shown here[image: udev prinout]. Is this approach more accurate than using "modalias" and is this the driver that may be occupying the device?

Comment: systemctl disable prevents the service from starting after you reboot, you need systemctl stop to stop it if you haven't rebooted.  Also you can find something under /sys that might tell you which module is using a device, even if it isn't a loadable module,  eg: I have /sys/bus/i2c/devices/i2c-10/device/driver/module is a symlink to ../../../../module/nouveau

Comment: Is it in use by the "gpio-pca953x" driver?

Comment: @TomV I updated my answer above

Comment: @Ian Abbott the system uses the tca9548a switch as an interface to the device but how can I figure out if that device is holding/blocking me from access?